# Conditional attributes in 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to use [conditional attributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-attributes) in Polymer 1.0? 
I've try to find it in [the migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html) and also in [Road to polymer](http://chuckh.github.io/road-to-polymer/) without success.

I know that in Polymer 1.0 there's a new [conditional template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if), but I don't want to duplicate my code.

So in 0.5 version we can had something like:

```html
<input readonly?={{my-boolean-expression}} (...)>
```

And, in 1.0, should we do it with a template?

```html
<template is="dom-if" if="{{my-boolean-expression}}">
      <input readonly (...)>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="!{{my-boolean-expression}}">
       <input (...)>
</template>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding).

What you will want to do is:

```
<input readonly$="{{my-boolean-expression}}">
```